# SSRS create on purpose an empty blank page for pdf

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way to create on purpose a last empty / blank page on my report? The problem i am facing is this: I want always the exported pdf to have even pages. So, i would like when the produced pages are odd, to add an empty page at the end so the total number to be even. Thank you.

Tried to pass the global variable TotalPages on the main body but it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to improve your question by providing some code what you have done at your side.

Comment: Add a rectangle to the end of the report and set it to pagebreak after. Then set the hidden property of the rectangle based on the number of pages. `TotalPages` can only be used in a header/footer so you would have to calculate how many pages you have based on your data.

Comment: If you want the extra-page rectangle to only appear in the PDF, check the RenderFormat.Name - `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF", True, False)`

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot calculate pages from data. Report creates many tables that are dynamic according to data of the userid. So, a user can have only 2 pages and some other user could have 4-5 pages etc.

Comment: That does not mean you cannot calculate the number of pages, it just means it's more difficult.